# Jquery effect behaving like a callback. order of events issue. Why?

Tags: jquery, callback

I am in the process of creating a jquery splash page to overlay a website. As the 2 boxes split apart, there is a box behind it which is suppose to fade out at the same time as split occurs but it wont work properly. It waits for the 2 boxes to split then after that is complete the box fades.

The callback is set **after** the black fades box so i'm not sure why this is happening.  The events are suppose to happen simultaneously. Is my code wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".left,.right").delay(800).animate({
                    width: 0
                }, 1100);
                $(".black").delay(2300).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, function () {

                    $(".left,.right,.black").css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #333;
                margin:0;
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            .left {
                background-color: #FFF;
                height: 100%;
                width: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                z-index: 999;
            }
            .right {
                background-color: #FFF;
                height: 100%;
                width: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                z-index: 999;
            }
            .black {
                background-color: #000;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                z-index: 998;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: show here your html document too.

Comment: Why do you have a 2.3 second delay on the black animation beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box waits before it fades because there is a 2300ms (2.3 second) delay before that animation.  It's not waiting for the 1st animation to finish, it's waiting 2.3 seconds.

Also, when the black box finishes fading, it hides all of them regardless of whether the 1st animation is done or not.

Try to change the delay on `.black` to 800 (the same as `.left` and `.right`).  Also make the animation times the same, so that they finish (and thus hide) at the same time.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/PVqec/

Comment: I was trying to use the delays to give a cooler looking effect. I wanted the black box to fade as the 2 white boxes start to open but it all happened so fast I was trying to adjust the timing.  what would be the best approach? I want the visitor to see the fade happen as those boxes separate

Comment: @DC1: Edit your question and add the HTML there.